# search-and-replace on PHP code before it is executed

Tags: php, apache

Is there a way to perform search and replace on PHP code **before** it is interpreted by PHP engine ?

Desired timeline:

1. PHP code is `<?php echo("hello"); ?>`.
2. Search and replace operation is `hello` → `good bye`
3. PHP code is now `<?php echo("good bye"); ?>`.
4. PHP engine interprets the code (output is `good bye`).

It is possible to manipulate the output of the PHP engine, using `ob_start` or even `mod_substitute` as an output filter of Apache. However, is it possible to manipulate the input of the PHP engine (PHP code, request, etc)?

**Edit:**

I'm working with thousands of PHP files and I don't want them to be modified. I would like to replace `host1` with `host2` in these files, since the files were copied from `host1` and they have to be executed on `host2`. Indeed, several tests are made on the host name.

Comment: If you are willing to fiddle with the PHP engine, probably, but why? Maybe elaborate a bit about your situation. What do you need this for?

Comment: Maybe if you give your use case for this we can help further?

Comment: So you want the replace() to be executed before the rest of your code? Could you not just put it at the top of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a php script that opens a `.php` file, makes the necessary replacement, then `include`s that file.

Comment: You all made the same suggestion. However yours is the shorter. All my requests will be processed by a single file using `mod_rewrite` (the original script to execute will be passed as a GET parameter). This file will implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Request is unusual)
Looks stupid. But if you really need it try this..
For example you need to change file `test.php` before execute it.
Try following steps (in `index.php` for example):
1) Open test.php for reading and get its content.
2) Replace everything you want.
3) Save changed text as `test2.php`
4) Include `test2.php`.

**EDIT**

Better thin why you need it? Try using [variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php).
It will help)

Answer (score 0):

You **should** study template engines like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) and various forms of [prefilters](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.register.prefilter.tpl).

Modifying code like this isn't good idea, however to answer your question... You may load original code, preprocess it and store in new file:

```
$contents = file_get_contents( 'original.php');
// ...
file_put_contents( 'new.php', $contents);
include( 'new.php')
```

But I don't see any valid use of this...

You also may possibly use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) but every time you do that a kitty dies (no really, it's dangerous function and there's really just a few valid uses of it).

Comment: Eval is bad.. Very very bad. If you only knew how many downvotes i vahe recieved for eval().

Comment: @BogdanBurim I though I've made it clear that it's bad practice.